# Removing multiple sections from a list using indexes

Tags: python, list

I want to remove sections by index from a list. i.e. from index 12:90 and index 100:120 etc.

I know I can't modify a list I'm looping over if I iterate from the start to the end of the list, so I tried looping from the end of the list to the start. This isn't working either as I can't seem to access the different elements of my reversed list.

This is my current test code I think it's obvious what I want to happen, but I have the error message: `TypeError: 'reversed' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

```
a = [5,7,23,5,2,6,2,7,98,3]
indexs = 0,2,5,7
widened_excluder = reversed(indexs)

for i in widened_excluder:
    if i != len(indexs)-1:
        start = widened_excluder[i+1]
        end = widened_excluder[i]
        del a[start:end]
```

**Edit:**
This is the function I'm using (when using real data) to get the ranges I want excluded:

```
def zero_excluder(curve, lnO, ts):
    indexs = curve.nonzero()
    indexs = indexs[0]
    zero_gap = []
    for i in indexs:
        if i > 5 and i < len(indexs) - 6:
            if indexs[i] - indexs[i-1] > 2:
                zero_gap.append([indexs[i-6], indexs[i+5]])
    for pair in zero_gap:
        start = pair[0]
        end = pair[1]+1
        del 

    lnO = lnO[indexs]
    ts = ts[indexs]
    return lnO, ts
```

Comment: How are you getting the ranges for the indexes you don't want? Are they coming form the user or do you have a set of ranges you know you don't need?

Comment: I've got a different function that gives me the range. I'll add the code as an edit to the question now.

Comment: Totally an aside but the plural of index is indices. Sorry but it's driving me nuts :-).

Comment: To explain about the error: `reversed` tries to be clever (and save space) and doesn't actually copy your list over. In fact, if you remove items from your original list, the `reversed(...)` item no longer works! You may need to make a copy, if you want to continue to approach it that way (e.g. `reversed(ln0[::])` with all the usual caveats of deep-copying and nested lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude many ranges and you can use numpy, the easiest way would be to create a mask and apply it to a copy of your data. A mask would have `True` for elements you want to retain, and `False` for elements you don't want:

```
# your data
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# slices you want to delete, i.e. 'zero_gap'
slices = [[2, 4], [7, 9]]

# create a mask of Trues and turn off elements
# that you want to remove
mask = np.ones(len(arr), dtype=np.bool)
for s in slices:
    mask[s[0] : s[1] + 1] = False

# apply a mask
remaining = np.copy(arr)[mask]
print remaining # [0, 1, 5, 6, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting elements one by one is bad in your case, as it hits performance hardly. Slicing syntax probably will do the trick:

```
l = range(200)
l2 = l[:12] + l[90:100] + l[120:]
```

Comment: so the first number in the brackets i.e. the 90 is exclusive and the last number is inclusive yeah?

Comment: Yes. And you can always check https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html for such minor stuff

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you have any idea how would I go about putting this into a loop for an arbitrary about of ranges? This would be instead of the last for loop (which doesn't actually do much atm) in the edit. I'd like it to modify lnO and ts so that the ranges in zero_gap are removed.